# How to partition switch to different subnet?

Tags: networking, router, switch

I have a router with 8 interfaces. Each interface is on its on subnet. All the cable from each interface is plugged into a single 48-port switch.

I feel that this implementation is rather strange. What is the correct way to do this to get 8 subnets? In addition, if each router interface is its own DHCP server, how does the devices from switch know which one to use? I am trying to avoiding configuring static ip

Comment: VLANs. does your switch support VLANs? if so, you would create groups of ports on the switch for each vlan/subnet pair, and connect one of these ports to the router port for that sub. then all the other ports in that vlan will get dhcp info from the pool served by the router port.

Comment: Yes! I am looking into VLANs now. So it is not odd at all to have 8 cables running from router into the same switch?

Comment: not if you actually need 8 subnets and only have the one switch, no not really. a more sophisticated solution might be to use trunking to share a single line to the router amongst all the vlans, but it is a more advanced and less concrete configuration and requires the router to understand vlans as well. 8 lines would mean that the router only needs to know how to route between the subs.

Comment: Its totally possible to trunk as a single cable but I am afraid that it is causing a bottle neck on one interface? 1GBs

Comment: I'm afraid that only you can tell us whether a single line is sufficient for your use-case. you can also look into Link Aggregation Groups to see if you can bundle two switch and two router ports together for double bandwidth. keep in mind that your router must be involved when clients on two vlans talk to each other, so depending on the router backplane and utilization, this whole endeavor may or may not work out for you in terms of performance.  it depends entirely on how its used.

Comment: In an enterprise environment you might see two connections port channeled together, with all the vLANs trunked on it. This would provide redundancy, higher bandwidth, and a simpler configuration, while reducing the number of ports required.

Answer (score 0):

Using 802.1Q VLAN tagging you can 'trunk' a single link to allow transport for all VLANs configured on both sides. Just make sure the link speed is high enough for the traffic total and all VLANs are configured on both sides in the exact same way.

Running multiple, physical links between switch and router requires VLANs in the switch anyway. Each VLAN defines which ports can talk to each other while ports in different VLANs cannot.

I'm pretty sure the current switch config has got several VLANs set up, each with untagged ports for the clients and the according router port. If you want to change the switch-router interconnect to support all VLANs you need to add all VLANs to the interconnect port. One VLAN may remain untagged, all the others must be tagged.

On the router you need to configure the port in the same way. Make sure the router ports are not in switch mode as multiple interconnects for a VLAN could cause a bridge loop unless spanning tree protocol (STP/RSTP/MSTP) is used.